# Show List of HighlightGraph Objects in Matrix

Tags: graphics, matrix

I'm new to *Mathematica* and can't get my problem solved.

I want to display a list of `HighlightGraph` objects in `MatrixForm` like `GraphicsGrid`.

This is my current tryout create a 3xn matrix

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Table[# &, {3}, {(Length[graphLst] / 3) + Mod[Length[graphLst], 3]}]
 ] /@ graphLst
```

This is the output.

> [image: Output]

I can't figure it out how to get this thing going.

Can you lend me some help?

Answer (score 6):

Since you provided no data, I'll create my own. `Partition` is your friend (read its documentation on how to handle non-rectangular results if your list of graphs is not a multiple of 3 in your case).:

```
graphs = HighlightGraph[CompleteGraph[#], {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
      Style[3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, Green]}] & /@ Range[3, 15];
```

And then make a 3XN grid:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[graphs, 3], Frame->All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks works very fine :-)
Is it also possible to label each graph in the grid specifically?
For example: above your first graph in the grid will be the label displayed {1, 2} (the vertices which are connected)